# General and specific ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Tried solving this but not sure it's correct. Does anyone have a chance to check it? Any ideas on optimizing my 'process' would also be appreciated.

For

$\frac{dK}{dt}=\lambda(P-K)$ where $K(0) = 0.2P$

General solution

$
dK = \lambda(P-K) \space dt \\
\frac{1}{(P-K)} \space dK = \lambda \space dt \\
\int \frac{1}{(P-K)} \space dK = \int \lambda \space dt\\
-ln(P-K) = \lambda t + C\\
-e^{ln(P-K)} = e^{\lambda t + C}\\
-P - K = e^{\lambda t + C}\\
-K = P + e^{\lambda t + C}\\
-(-K) = -(P + e^{\lambda t + C})
$

$
K(t) = -P - e^{\lambda t + C} = -P - e^{\lambda t} e^C
$

Particular solution

$
0.2P = -P - e^{\lambda (0) + C}=-P - e^{\lambda (0)} e^C = -P - e^C\\
-e^C = P + 0.2P\\
ln(e^C) = -ln(1.2P)\\
C = -ln(1.2P)
$

$
K(t) = -P - e^{\lambda t} (-1.2P)
$

---

## Potential fix

General solution

$
-ln|(P-K)| = \lambda t + C\\
e^{ln|(P-K)^{-1}|} = e^{\lambda t + C}\\
|\frac{1}{(P-K)}| = e^{\lambda t + C}\\
\frac{1}{(P-K)} = Ce^{\lambda t}\\
1 = PCe^{\lambda t}-KCe^{\lambda t}\\
PCe^{\lambda t} - 1 = KCe^{\lambda t}\\
$

$
K(t) = \frac{PCe^{\lambda t}-1}{Ce^{\lambda t}}\\
$

Particular solution

$
0.2P = \frac{PCe^{\lambda (0)}-1}{Ce^{\lambda (0)}}\\
0.2P = \frac{PC-1}{C}\\
0.2PC = PC - 1\\
-0.8PC = - 1\\
C=\frac{1}{0.8P}
$

$
K(t) = \frac{P(\frac{1}{0.8P})e^{\lambda t}-1}{(\frac{1}{0.8P})e^{\lambda t}}
$

Checking

$
K(0) = \frac{P(\frac{1}{0.8P})e^{\lambda (0)}-1}{(\frac{1}{0.8P})e^{\lambda (0)}} = \frac{\frac{P}{0.8P}-1}{\frac{1}{0.8P}}=(\frac{1}{0.8}-1)0.8P=0.25\cdot0.8P=0.2P
$

Comment: $-\log a=\log a^{-1}$

Comment: You can check your solution by computing $dK/dt$

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have added a potential 'fix', but still a bit unsure of myself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you went from $$-\log(P-K)=\lambda t+C$$ to $$-e^{\log(P-K)}=e^{\lambda t+C}$$ you fell into a trap --- the left side should be $e^{-\log(P-K)}$, which is a very different thing. You made another blunder on the next step, but you were already lost by then.

Comment: Thanks for checking it. Trying to take it from there in the original post, based on all your inputs. Still curious if I missed anything, or if it could be done any simpler!

Comment: Looks good to me.